# Does Dart have support for the FTP protocol

Tags: dart, dart-io, dart-http

Does Dart have any support for the FTP protocol. In particular code running on the server not the client.

thanks
Richard

Answer (score 1):

https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:html.HttpRequest says

```
HttpRequest can be used to obtain data from HTTP and FTP protocols, and is useful for AJAX-style page updates.
```

I don't know if there is more necessary to get FTP support as you might want it.

Comment: I'd assume that the HttpRequest can only do passive FTP client connections. The full FTP protocol is more complex than that, allowing for example setting up a transfer between two other hosts, and the server-side has to handle the full protocol.

Comment: the http package can only be used on a browser client

Comment: @richard You are right and I couldn't find anything about Dart server side and FTP.